# Conditional formatting of cell based on the conditional formatting of another cell

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I would like to have a cell be highlighted based on whether another cell is highlighted as well. For instance:

[image]
If "MC-Business Level 1 Data Rate I" cell is highlighted I would want the cell containing "MC-BE Value Face to Face" to be automatically highlighted as well.

What would be the proper course of action in order to make this happen?

Comment: Use the same trigger that formats one to format the other.

Comment: That's the issue. I cannot use the same condition that caused the initial cell to be highlighted. The second cell should be highlighted based only on  the fact that the first cell was highlighted.

Comment: Why not?  What was the condition?

Comment: To do it on the highlight will require vba, as functions cannot inherently detect the format of other cells.

Comment: The condition for the original cell was based on a short description. For instance, the description for the cell "MC-Business Level 1 Data Rate I" was "Data Rate I." The second cell that should be highlighted as a result of the original cell being highlighted is "MC-BE Value Face to Face". This cell doesn't contain the original description "Data Rate I".

Comment: So say your first cell in in Column A and your second is column B.  In the Applies to: you would put `B:B` and the formula would be `=isnumber(search("Data Rate I",A1))`

Comment: Oh you're right! I see your logic. I think I got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same conditional format and apply it to other ranges. This works best if the condition is expressed with a formula, so the comparison cell can be referenced absolutely. Note the $ sign for the column reference.

```
=isnumber(search("Data Rate I",$A1))
```

Apply that format to your first column by selecting it and then creating the format. After that, open the Rules Manager and edit the "Applies to" box. Enter a comma and then click the other column you want to apply this to. The screenshot shows the one rule applied to columns A and E.

[image]